Parsing Redshift metalized view Issue
Input stream.
{
  "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
  "eventID": "101",
  "eventName": "TEST",
  "userIdentity": null,
  "recordFormat": "application/json",
  "tableName": "TEST_dev",
  "dynamodb": {
    "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1714401906352737,
    "Keys": {
      "ID": {
        "S": "TEST_1"
      }
    },
    "NewImage": {
      "ID": {
        "S": "TEST_1"
      },
      "urlDetails": {
        "L": [
          {
            "M": {
              "type": {
                "S": "Hello"
              },
              "url": {
                "S": "Hello.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "M": {
              "type": {
                "S": "HI"
              },
              "url": {
                "S": "HI.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "M": {
              "type": {
                "S": "TESTING"
              },
              "url": {
                "S": "TESTING.com"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "SizeBytes": 427,
    "ApproximateCreationDateTimePrecision": "MICROSECOND"
  },
  "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
}

I have created the view and parsing the individual fields .like below
select data.dynamodb."NewImage"."ID"."S"::varchar(255) as ID from view;
Similarly I am looking to parse urlDetails field also.
Expected output for urlDetails field;
[
  {
    "type": "Hello",
    "url": "Hello.com"
  },
  {
    "type": "Hi",
    "url": "Hi.com"
  },
  {
    "type": "TESTING",
    "url": "TESTING.com"
  }
]

I tried select data.dynamodb."NewImage"."urlDetails"."L"."M"."type"."S" as url from view;
But its showing NULL

Bill Weiner - Please suggest

Anand, I got your callout but I’m out of office right now (sailboat delivery).  You should be able to get the first element with - data.dynamodb."NewImage"."urlDetails"."L"[0]."M"."type"."S" - “L” is an array.  To get all the elements you will need to unnest the array.  See - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html.  I’ll be back in the office next weekend

Thanks for the suggestions Bill Weiner
Its working
